# Applying textLength to SVG tspan elements inline (horizontal)

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to do something that should be  simple: display a word (an SVG `text` element) in which each character has a different colour. I did this programmatically: I split the string into characters, and inserted each character into a `tspan` element, each of which is inside a `text` element. I used the `textLength` attribute for spacing.

I tried so many permutations, but can't find a solution that works in all browsers.

Here's some code (just the SVG). Three examples, just to show how different browsers behave. The third one is what I want. It works in Chrome, but every other browser presents it differently:

```html
<svg width = "250px" height = "100px">
  <style>
    text {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>

  // A regular text element:
  <text y = "30px" textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 10%)">
    greengradient
  </text>

  // A text element with tspan elements:
  <text y = "60px">
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 70%)">green</tspan>
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 10%)">gradient</tspan>
  </text>

  // A text element with a tspan element for every character:
  <text y = "90px">
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 70%")>g</tspan>
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 65%")>r</tspan>
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 60%")>e</tspan>
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 55%")>e</tspan>
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 50%")>n</tspan>
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 45%")>g</tspan>
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 40%")>r</tspan>
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 35%")>a</tspan>
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 30%")>d</tspan>
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 25%")>i</tspan>
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 20%")>e</tspan>
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 15%")>n</tspan>
    <tspan textLength = "250px" fill = "hsl(120, 100%, 10%")>t</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Is there a browser-consistent way to apply `textLength` to inline `tspan` elements?

Comment: I havn't got the time to do cross-browser testing right now, but I have two remarks I think you should take into account: 1. All whitespace inside a `<text>` element is rendered, even if they are outside `<tspan>` - so be sure they match between the variants. 2. `textLength` is to be applied to just the element that should have the computed length, not to its children. In this case, it's always the `<text>` element, not the `<tspan>`. Additionally, a `textLength` for only one typographic character cannot be valid, because only advances _between_ the first and last character can be adjusted.

Comment: Thanks @ccprog. On point 2, I had thought that, too, yet it is only by applying `textLength` to the `tspan` elements that it works in  Chrome. I just tried your method (applying it only to the `text` element) and found it only works in Firefox when I do it that way! The reason I was applying `textLength` to single characters was purely to fit them to space.

Comment: If you want to apply a gradient to the text why not just apply  a linearGradient rather than colouring each letter?

Comment: You should create a linear gradient like this: `<linearGradient id="lg" >
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="hsl(120, 100%, 70%)"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="hsl(120, 100%, 10%)"></stop>
  </linearGradient>` and then fill the text: `fill = "url(#lg)"`

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson & @enxaneta :) Yes, that's simpler and more effective. I guess the question is now only theoretical: is there a way to apply `textLength` to `tspan` elements that works across browsers? Probably not yet.

Comment: @Markus download the source code to Firefox and create a patch for https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=890692

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer (and end) this question, with thanks to [Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) and [enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).

After experimenting, there's *no* way to apply `textLength` to inline `tspan` elements consistently across browsers. The standard is still being developed. A few examples:

**Firefox:**

[image: firefox]

**Chrome:**

[image: chrome]

**Edge:**

[image: edge]

The other question -- how to apply gradient colour to `text` elements -- is easier than my convoluted first attempt. Apply a `linearGradient` element to the SVG, then link it to the `text` element:

```html
<svg width = "300px" height = "40px">
  <linearGradient id="gradient">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="hsl(120, 100%, 70%)"></stop>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="hsl(120, 100%, 10%)"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
  <style>
    text {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
  <text y = "30px" textLength = "300px" fill = "url(#gradient)">
    greengradient
  </text>
</svg>
```